# How do I select a jstree node by id and pathid?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to select a jstree node whose `id` and `pathid` matches. I could not find any questions related to this. Is it possible in jQuery?

```
this._specTree.jstree("select_node", "#" + ID);
```

With the above line can select a node, but I want to check for `pathid` as well for that node. How can I do this?